# When is it applied & said as "striped" or "striped?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, pronunciation

A long time ago I heard someone ask this question, but I was only in elementary and this kid was in high school, but when is it applied and pronounced "striped" vs "striped," the key pronunciation difference being you've got one sounding like "st" as in the same, "ri" pronounced like rye, "ped" like that at the end of ripped, BUT the other version has it to be the same with the "st" and the "ri" but instead of like at the end of ripped, it's "pid" like at the end of stupid.

So "**is that a *stry-pt* shirt,**" or "**is that a *stripid* patterned shirt?**"

I feel like I've heard it used in the stripid way, and when I heard it, it sounded to be very correct, recollecting on that same story I shared in the beginning, but now have since forgotten and can't remember if there is even a pronunciation difference, and if so, when is it applied and why.

Comment: I am used to the 'e' being silent (in Australia), so stry-pt. It is sometimes pronounced stry-ped when reading poetry. I can't comment on other varieties of English.

Comment: "Stripid"? Never heard that. The closest sounding thing I can think of is *stripped* (as from *strip*), which is a very different word from *striped* (as from *stripe*). Or *triffid*, but that's a fictional plant.

Answer (score 1):

You could wear a 'striped' [strypt] shirt, or more colloquially a 'stripy' [strypi] shirt, but not a 'strypid' one, no matter how you spell it.

Some words have ecclesiastic or poetic pronunciations where the last vowel is pronounced to keep the meter - such as blessed, though these are often given hints in how they are spelled. You will see bless'd or blessèd, for instance.

There's no version of 'stripe' that will give you stripèd, and if any poet ever forced it, they would probably have used the accent to make you aware.

There's the remote possibility someone tortured 'stripy' to give 'stripied', in a forced cute-ism, but that's not one you need to be carrying around in your word arsenal.